# Update não comita alterações no banco

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-mvc-5, npgsql

Boa noite pessoal!
Sou novato em *ASP NET MVC* e estou fazendo um `CRUD` simples com banco **PostgreSql**. Já implementei o `Insert`, o Delete e `Get`, mas o `Update` não está salvando as alterações no banco. Debugando, percebi que ele faz todos os passos corretamente, até o "`commit`" do `UPDATE`, mas quando dou `GET` novamente para aquele registro, ele continua  igual. Não retorna nenhum erro , nem nada. Segue o meu método abaixo:

```
 public Guid Update(AreaInteresse area)
    {
        using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            //Inicia a transação
            using (var trans = con.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Transaction = trans;
                    cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE areainteresse SET descricao=@descricao WHERE id= @id";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", Convert.ToString(area.Id));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("descricao", area.Descricao);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //commit na transação
                    trans.Commit();
                    return area.Id;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //rollback da transação
                    trans.Rollback();
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Alguém tem idéia do que poderia ser? Parece que ele não está executando o "COMMIT" no banco, pois o ID chega corretamente até o parameter e converto ele para string pois o campo do banco é um character varying (36).

Comment: O campo Id não deveria se atualizar automaticamente após o Commit. Você precisaria realizar um refresh nessa instância. Confira no banco se os dados estão ou não sendo atualizados. E outro detalhe é que você jamais deveria precisar alterar o id de uma entidade.

Comment: O campo Id não se atualiza automaticamente. É passado todos os atributos da classe (inclusive o id da classe a ser atualizada), mas só é atualizado o atributo "Descrição" da tabela AreaInteresse. Consultando o banco pelo PGAdmin, o dado continua inalterado.